# Why doen't this code separate the given numbers into different columns in a .csv file?

Tags: csv

I've tried to create a program which inserts two numbers into an excel spreadsheet (each one into it's own column). The excel format is .csv.
This is the written code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(){
    int n1 = 6, n2 = 1;

    std::ofstream my_excel;
    my_excel.open("test.csv");
    if (!my_excel.is_open()) return 0;

    std::cout << "The excel file was successfully opened!\n";
    my_excel << n1 << "," << n2;
    my_excel.close();

    return 0;
}
```

This was the expected result in the .csv file:

[image: This was the expected result in the .csv file]

This is the actual result I got when I ran the code:

[image: This is the actual result I got when I ran the code]

Why weren't the numbers separated into their respective columns? (Ty in advance for your trouble!)

Comment: what is the seperator used when you open the file in the spreadsheet editor? The C in CSV is not always to be taken literally.

Comment: Post the images directly, not as links. This is not a c++ problem, you just have to correctly import the CSV into Excel.

Comment: you have to pin down where the error actually happens. The C++ code looks ok. Can you edit a .csv manually and import it in execl to get the desired result? Unless you can do that you can be sure that the issue is not in the C++ code.

Comment: The other comments in mind... I commonly use `\t` as the column separator (and consequently, I call that tab-separated text instead of CSV). ;-)

Comment: For starters, who says these are two numbers, instead of a single one, `6,1`? CSV isn't an Excel file, it's just a text file. If you double-click on it, Excel has no idea what's in there. It will try to **import** the data using the current user's locale settings for decimal, thousand and list separators. In countries where `,` is the decimal separator (half the world), the list separator is `;`

Comment: If you use the `Data` menu on the other hand, you can actually tell Excel what separators to use

Comment: This is not a c++ question though. If the OP also agrees, I would suggest modifying tags.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That makes sense, Excel by default right aligns numeric values, and left aligns text, this would suggest that this is indeed a number.

Comment: @Maaz afaik you can edit the tags (and OP will have to accept or decline), though imho the question needs more than just adding the tag because its missing information that only OP knows

Comment: Excel files (ie `xlsx`) are ZIP files containing well-formed XML files. If you really want to generate Excel files you'll have to find a library to create them. You could create the XML files yourself but it's a lot easier to use an existing library. A [GitHub searrch](https://github.com/search?l=C%2B%2B&p=1&q=xlsx+c%2B%2B&type=Repositories) shows that `OpenXLSX` and `xlnt` are the most starred libraries

Comment: Well the problem was just the import of the csv to the spreadsheet. The default separator was `\t` so I just swapped out the comma for that. Ty all for the quick explanations. And ty for the extra info about `OpenXLSX` and `xlnt`.